# excel vba combo chart to determine which should be area and which is line markers based on dynamic selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform  a combo chart with area and the line markers. Since it is a dynamic chart.But if the user interchanges the Population and the metric between the rows then it is not performing as wanted. I want the population to always be a area while the metric to be the line markers.Also the population should be secondary axis aswell.

```
sub test() 
Dim myString As String
myString = Selection.Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes.addchart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myString)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlArea
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
End sub
```

My data set is like this

```
  STATISTIC SEP-10 OCT-10 NOV-10 DEC-10 JAN-10 FEB-10 MAR-10
  METRIC    0       0      111.1   55.1  0      0      0
  Population 7      1      18      36    98     1      1
```

Here my code performs as required but if the rows of metric and population are interchanged then the metric is used as area chart while population is used as line graph. Can I make it such that it checks which row contains POP (should be case insenitive) to be the area graph and secondary axis while other to be line marker.

The suggested answer for the below one gave (code by AU)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further edited my answer. it is working still in excel 2007, may please modify according to your requirements.

```
Sub test()
Dim myString As String
myString = Selection.Address

Dim Rng, RngX, RngMet, RngPop As Range, popRow, MetRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
Set Rng = .Range(myString)
Set RngX = .Range(Rng.Cells(1, 2), Rng.Cells(1, Rng.Columns.Count))
MetRow = 2
popRow = 3
    If InStr(1, UCase(Rng.Cells(2, 1).Value), "POP") > 0 Then
    MetRow = 3
    popRow = 2
    End If

Set RngPop = .Range(Rng.Cells(popRow, 2), Rng.Cells(popRow, Rng.Columns.Count))
Set RngMet = .Range(Rng.Cells(MetRow, 2), Rng.Cells(MetRow, Rng.Columns.Count))

.Shapes.AddChart(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myString)
'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = RngMet
'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Rng.Cells(MetRow, 1).Value

'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = RngPop
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlArea
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = Rng.Cells(popRow, 1).Value
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = RngX

ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = 2
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "MMM-yy"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It says object does not support this property or method at ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.NewSeries location

Comment: Edited my answer, Please try and feedback.

Comment: 2 things one it messed up the date below x axis- tick labels(not showing SEP-10 etc. 2) the series still shows POP instead of Metric in the graph so basically the labelling is still reversed though it is performing as needed.I mean the legend shows opposite

Comment: In the chart that you showed I wanted population to be area and Metric to be line markers. Also I dont want the stat to be showed in the chart, that is just the heading